# file_get_contents() permission denied failed to open stream

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

Llevo, si es que estoy en lo correcto, 4 horas (y seguidas) buscando en todo el foro de Stackoverflow (para que no me digan que eche un vistazo al tour), asímismo como múltiples hilos en otros foros como DigitalOcean, la solución a el problema famoso de permission denied, failed to open stream, con la función `file_get_contents()`

Intenté, mediante shell, haciendo múltiples `chmod`, entre estos, `777`, asímismo como `chown` a el directorio en que se encuentra el archivo que quiero leer, `/root/test2/plugins/RLBT`

Este es mi código:
`/var/www/html/bt_api.php`

```
<?php
...
echo file_get_contents("/root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json");
```

Y el error completo:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/bt_api.php on line 34
```

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Comment: Puedes verificar si tienes permiso de lectura en ese archivo que intentas leer?

Comment: Tal como indique en mi pregunta, intenté con `chmod` y `chown`, y sí, tengo permisos para leer y escribir, pero por alguna razón, con PHP no funciona.

Comment: $json = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json');

Comment: sigue siendo un problema de permisos, apache y php necesitan acceso a la carpeta padre (y si está bien configurado el server necesitan permisos de todo el árbol) por lo cual te aconsejo mover el archivo fuera de `/root` create una carpeta en `/home` onda `/home/codigo` y asignale owner y grupo `www-data`. asi podes leerlo desde `/home/codigo/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que intentas leer un archivo al que le pertenece otro usuario; la carpeta `/root` le pertenece al usuario `root` mientras que el usuario que se utiliza para ejecutar apache o php es `www-data`.

Puedes comprobar qué usuario es el que ejecuta el script escribiendo esto en un archivo php:

```
<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>
```

normalmente el directorio `/var/www` tiene permisos sobre el mismo usuario.

Ahora que sabes que existe una diferencia entre usuarios, puedes tomar alguno de estos tres casos:

> Mover el archivo a la carpeta `/var/www/html` y cambiar los permisos para que el usuario `www-data` pueda leerlo con:

```
$ sudo mv /root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json /var/www/html/
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/html/verified.json
```

> Crear un enlace simbólico (acceso directo) al archivo ubicado en `/root` a la carpeta `/var/www/html`. En este método si el archivo ubicado en `/root` sufre alguna modificación por otro usuario, los cambios se ven reflejados automáticamente en el enlace. Para ello:

```
$ sudo ln -s /root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json /var/www/html/
$ sudo chmod 644 /root/test2/plugins/RLBT/verified.json
```

> Agregar el usuario `www-data` al grupo `root`, este método es **peligroso** ya que le estarás dando permiso a cualquier usuario en internet acceder al servidor:

```
$ sudo adduser www-data root
```

<sub>Úsese bajo su propio riesgo.</sub>

> Aqui la info: [How to make php webpage to access the file in /root directory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329322/how-to-make-php-webpage-to-access-the-file-in-root-directory)

Comment: Esto comenta Carla: Intenté el 2do y el 3er método como me dijiste, sin éxito alguno. El error es el mismo. El último que intenté fue el de los enlaces simbólicos, y ahora hago file_get_contents("verified.json")